# Stuck with understanding css of webpages

Tags: css, templates

The thing is that I have learnt css well but i don't quite understand a template when trying to clone one .
I don't understand how and in what manner a thing is done.
If there is any tip or exercises e.t.c on internet to better understand a webcode or template then help me with it . I'll be grateful!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm browsing the web page.My advice is to review and code a lot of themes.